# Exploring formal limit definition

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I found a few demonstrations on the Wolfram Demonstration Project site that help users to explore the formal definition of a limit. That is,
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$
if and only if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that whenever
$$0<\left|\,x-a\,\right|<\delta,$$
it is true that
$$\left|\,f(x)-L\,\right|<\epsilon.$$
I also tried exploring this site. Does anyone have some other nice examples or demonstrations that they use to assist their students in understanding this definition? For example: Use a graph to find a number $\delta$ such that
$$\left|\sqrt{4x+1}-3\right|<0.5\qquad\text{whenever}\qquad0<|x-2|<\delta$$ 
Both static or manipulate examples are welcome.

Thanks

**Update:** Ok, here is a first attempt.

```
DynamicModule[{f, a, L, zoomfirst},
 f[x_] := Sqrt[4 x + 1];
 a = 2;
 L = Limit[f[x], x -> a];
 (* zoomfirst is number of units to the right
 of x =a. *)
 zoomfirst = 3;
 Manipulate[
  Show[
   Plot[f[x], {x, a - zoom, a + zoom},
    PlotRange -> {{a - zoom, a + zoom}, {L - 2 \[Epsilon], 
       L + 2 \[Epsilon]}}],
   Plot[{L + \[Epsilon], L - \[Epsilon]}, {x, a - zoom, a + zoom},
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Dashed, GrayLevel[0.8]],
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}],
   Graphics[{
     {Blue, Dashed, 
      Line[{{a, L - 2 \[Epsilon]}, {a, L}, {a - zoom, L}}]}
     }]
   ], {{\[Epsilon], 1}, 0.0001, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{zoom, zoomfirst}, 0.0001, zoomfirst, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
  {{p, {a, L - \[Epsilon]}}, Locator}
  ]]
```

[image]

Here are a couple of questions:

1. I'd like to replace my locator with a red dashed vertical line that moves as I select and move it with my mouse. I'd also like the x-value of the line to appear at the bottom of the red-dashed line, updating as it moves. Can I do that without using the word Dynamic?
2. I'd like to add a second locator with a solid black line that travels from (x,L-2[Epsilon]) to the graph of f vertically, than horizontally to the left side, the end of which I want labeled f(x).
3. After moving the first locator to where the vertical red dashed line intersects where the graph leaves the filled region on the left, I'd like another red, dashed vertical line locator that I can move to there it intersects where the graph leaves the filled region on the right. Again, I would like to label it at the bottom with x-value, updating it as the vertical dashed red line moves. Again, possible without using the word Dynamic?

Comment: Not sure what others will think in terms of the MSE forum charter, but this question might be a better fit for community.wolfram.com (Wolfram Community site). Don't get me wrong, I like the question.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau et al. I've added an update to my post.

Comment: Gets my vote, with that update.